# How to extract text embedded in span?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes, tradingview-api

I have a problem guys, and I deeply appreciate if you help me. Actually, I wanted to extract the text in the below HTML code from the website tradingview.

```
<div class="container-wd6ACMnd widgetWrapper-3D6MmRkq"><span class="bid- 
jWOxMVeS">48080.64<span>×0.10626500099897385</span></span><span class="ask- 
3W3yMk6V">48080.65<span>×1.3940399885177612</span></span></div>
```

I have the following code, but it does no work and makes the error: ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'text') . Strange is that it works, for example, for extracting the BTC price which exactly has the same HTML code except the text is attached to "div class". Thank you very much for helping me in advance.

```
[1]  !apt update
     !apt install chromium-chromedriver
     !pip install selenium
     from IPython.display import clear_output
     clear_output()


 [2] from selenium import webdriver
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

     options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     options.add_argument('--headless')
     options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
     options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

     url="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDT/technicals/"
     wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
     wd.get(url)
     while True:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "lxml")
                h1 = soup.find("span", class_="bid-jWOxMVeS").text
                print(f'\r{h1}', end=" ")
```

Comment: .get_text() is the right way.

Comment: there are no class `bid-*` on page url above